# Pause action not working properly in roku

Tags: scene, roku, brightscript

I am developing a roku channel by using scene graph. I am using video node to play video and also disabled default UI of video like progress bar, buffering bar etc...

I want to develope custom progress bar using video node. My issue is...

To pause video for first time, I have to press 2 times pause button to pause. After that single press is working for me.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will give a better idea of what may be happening. However, based on what you have described, it seems the first time you are pressing the pause button, you might be in fact playing the content and then on the second press, it is in fact pausing. After that every press alternates between play and pause.

The value that you are setting to the "control" field of the Video node initially, will make this clear.